# Notification custom layout does not work on Android 11

Tags: android, notifications

In my Android app I use notification with custom layout.
It works perfectly from Android 5 to Android 10. In Android 11 a notification appears, but it is empty.
I cannot find any problem in code.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hi @Podborovcan, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you give more details about what you are actually doing, like the piece of code where you set custom notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Some lines of my code, but code works perfectly from Android 5 to Android 10, as I have written:

```
    private static NotificationCompat.Builder getBuilder(Context context){
        RemoteViews collapsedView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.view_collapsed_notification);
        RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.view_expanded_notification_small);
        String channelId = NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_heart_fill);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
        builder.setCustomContentView(collapsedView);
        builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);
        return builder;
    }


    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getBuilder(context).build());
```